# Conditional distribution of two dependent gaussian random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, gaussian

Suppose we had two multivariate Gaussian random variables, with one being an affine transformation of the first $$X\sim\mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol\mu,\mathbf{\Sigma}), \\Y=\mathbf{A}X+\mathbf{b},$$ with $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n},\mathbf{b}\in\mathbb{R}^m$. I understand that it's a well-established fact that we can compute the marginal distribution of $Y$ as $Y\sim\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{A}\boldsymbol\mu +\mathbf{b},\mathbf{A\Sigma A}^\top).$

My question is:

- **What different ways are there to compute the conditional distribution** $p(Y|X)?$ do we have to compute the joint distribution--computing the cross-covariance terms--and then apply the formula involving the Schur complement for the conditional? Is there no faster way given the relationship between the random variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $Y$ is measurable with respect to $X$, $p(Y|X)$ will be a $\delta$ distribution at $AX + b$.  The only randomness is in $X$, so if you condition that out you get a non-random result.

Comment: Fantastic, succinct answer--thanks! So I guess if we add randomness via something like $Y=\mathbf{A}X+\mathbf{b} + W$, for $W\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\mathbf{Q})$, we get that $p(Y\mid X)\sim\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{A}X+\mathbf{b}, \mathbf{Q})$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.